# Write a recursive method that counts the number of nodes in a chain of linked nodes

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I try many coding to solve the question bellow but also cannot find the answer. Can anyone help me solve my problem and tell me where is the wrong coding??

```
/** Task: Recusively counts the nodes in a chain.
* @param start the first node
* @returns the number of nodes in the linked chain */
public int countNodes(Node start)
{
if (start == null) 

// base case

{
  countNodes (Node start);

// recursive case
else

System.out.println (start.data);
return start.next;
}
} // end countNodes
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far, then we can help you improve it. And if this is homework, please tag it accordingly :-)

Comment: Is this a homework assignment or something?

Comment: I added the `homework` tag accordingly. Please do so in the future. Homework assignments are handled slightly differently from "normal" questions on SO - we don't do anyone's homework, but we are glad to offer hints and corrections if we see that you have done your share of efforts to solve the problem :-)

Comment: the coding i write down already can help me check where I'm do wrong and mistake. thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it helps to think of it like this: the number of nodes is 1 for the current node plus the result of counting the rest of the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Lets create a Recursive function called `countNodes(Node node)`

1. If `node` is `null`, that means there are no more Nodes so count = 0
2. Else There are 1 + countNodes(node.next)

Say you have a list A->B->C->D->NULL

```
countNodes(NodeA) = 1 + countNodes(NodeB)
countNodes(NodeA) = 1 + (1 + countNodes(NodeC))
countNodes(NodeA) = 1 + (1 + (1 + countNodes(NodeD)))
countNodes(NodeA) = 1 + (1 + (1 + (1 + 0))))
```

So, 4 is our answer.

Answer (score 0):

In recursion you shouldn't use the same argument for the next equation, basically, you should do some simple calculation, in your case add one, and call your function again with the "next" value of the argument. Obviously, to be able to solve this problem using recursion, there should be possibility to move from the current node to the next one.